# SSIS SQL Task with parameters not creating temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, dataflowtask

I've got a SQL task that creates a temp table, then a data flow task that selects from that temp table. Everything works fine and dandy, but when I add a parameter to the SQL task, the data flow task fails, saying the temp table wasn't created. Hard coding the parameter values works.

The retain same connection option is true, metadata is set, and my Int32 variables are mapped as long with names 0 and 1 and size -1 for oledb.

I've managed to replicate it on a smaller scale

SQL Task

```
DECLARE @Yesterday DATETIME
DECLARE @Today DATETIME

DECLARE @StartDisposition INT = ?
DECLARE @EndDisposition INT = ?

SET @Yesterday = CONVERT (date, DATEADD(day, @StartDisposition, GETDATE()))
SET @Today = CONVERT (date, DATEADD(day, @EndDisposition, GETDATE()))

SELECT @StartDisposition AS A, @Yesterday AS B, @Today AS C INTO #TempT
```

Data Flow Task, or just a SQL Task for this purpose

`SELECT * FROM #TempT`

So something with the parameters seems to be messing up the creation of the temp table.

Thanks

Using a String variable expression for the query worked. Here's how it went.

```
"DECLARE @Yesterday DATETIME
DECLARE @Today DATETIME

DECLARE @StartDisposition INT = " + (DT_STR, 20, 1252)@[User::StartDisposition] + "
DECLARE @EndDisposition INT =  " + (DT_STR, 20, 1252)@[User::EndDisposition] + "

SET @Yesterday = CONVERT (date, DATEADD(day, @StartDisposition, GETDATE()))
SET @Today = CONVERT (date, DATEADD(day, @EndDisposition, GETDATE()))

SELECT @StartDisposition AS A, @Yesterday AS B, @Today AS C INTO #TempT"
```

Then in the SQL Task you change the SQLSourceType to Variable

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing too about TEMP tables with SSIS. I read somewhere they may not work in 2012 for some reason. Hopefully someone gives a solid explanation.

Comment: Yeah hopefully. I'm working in 2010 though. I just tried it with the sql source as a variable, and it seemed to work. I'd rather not resort to that though.

Comment: I got the same error in 2012, haven't tried 2010. In 2008 temp tables work fine in the procedures executed through data flow tasks.

Comment: Why load the item into a #table and then have a DFT pull from the temp table? Couldn't you just use the query that populates the #table? Or possibly turn this into a stored procedure?

Comment: I'm using a column that's in the temp table to grab data from another table. I can't create procedures on the server either.

Comment: I remember running into this issue. Instead of using temp I created a table and dropped it when I was done.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create tables on that server.

Comment: Putting the query into a variable expression got it to work. Thanks for your help guys. I'll put the expression in my question in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but you can work around by creating the temp separately in a SQL Task before your task to load the table.  Doing the SELECT INTO #temp with parameter seems to be issue but when doing INSERT #temp with parameter works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] your answer and post some code that demonstrates what you are describing?

Answer (score -1):

Sometime strange.But It can be solved if we create global temp table ( ##TempT)